# want to read json string from php on iOS

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, json

I am  actually doing a app that receives data from a PHP Script which codes the response in JSON object.

I receive the data in my iOS app but when I want to search once value in the json object I dont know how to do it.s

The code that connects with the script:

> ```
> NSString *myRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"user=%@",userReceived];
>    NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [myRequestString UTF8String] length: [myRequestString length]];
> NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL
> URLWithString:@"/scripts/consultaUsuario.php"]];
>
> [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
> [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
> [request setHTTPBody:myRequestData];
>
> NSURLResponse *response;
> NSError *error;
>
> NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
> NSString *content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[returnData bytes]];
>
> NSData *contentData = [content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
>
>  NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:contentData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];
>
> if (dict) {
>     abogados = [[dict objectForKey:@"datos"] retain];
> }
>
> NSLog (@"Elemento: %@", [abogados objectAtIndex:0]);
> ```

When I execute this code, I get:

```
2014-02-13 12:27:05.409 appAbogados[25804:f803] 1
2014-02-13 12:27:05.448 appAbogados[25804:f803] Elemento: {
    "Avis_Guardia" = 1;
    "Avis_Vista" = 0;
    CanalHabitualAbogado = 00;
    CertNombre = "";
    ClienteSerieTurnoOficio = 00;
    ClienteTurnoOficio = "";
    CodigoAbogado = 2;
    CodigoColegioAbogado = 0;
    CodigoPostal = "";
    Desc1 = 0;
    Desc2 = 0;
    Desc3 = 0;
    Desc4 = 0;
    Desc5 = 0;
    Desc6 = 0;
    Direccion = "";
    ESPECIAL = "";
    EmpresaPredeterminadaEosCodigo = "";
    EmpresaPredeterminadaEosNombre = "";
    IPF = 0;
    IdOutLook = "";
    ImportIdentificacion = "";
    Mail = "";
    MostrarInforme = 1;
    NIF = "";
    Nombre = OTRO;
    NombreColegioAbogado = "";
    NombreComun = "";
    Notas = "";
    NumeroColegiado = 0;
    Pais = "";
    Poblacion = "";
    Provincia = "";
    SerialCertificado = 1;
    Sexo = " ";
    "Tiempo_Avis" = 1;
    "Tiempo_Tipo" = 3;
    TipoVia = "";
    UltimaModificacion = "Feb  7 2014 04:22:47:000PM";
    Usuario = "maria jesus";
}
```

I want to get the values for the keys "CodigoAbogado" and "Nombre" and save into variable, but I dont know how to do it, I tried some code from the web but it doesn't work.

(When I send the data from PHP script I use the function json_encode.)

Comment: `[abogados objectAtIndex:0]` is a dictionary that contains listed keys. Use `objectForKey:` to get the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here your code

```
NSDictionary *elemento = [abogados objectAtIndex:0];
if ([elemento objectForKey:@"CodigoAbogado"]) {
    NSInteger codigoAbogado = [[elemento objectForKey:@"CodigoAbogado"] integerValue];
}
if ([elemento objectForKey:@"Nombre"]) {
    NSString *nombre = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [elemento objectForKey:@"Nombre"]];
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, ur code is correct. I didnt see that i get the whole content of the json object in a cell of my array. U did a new dictionary from the array, then u access to the value. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Repeat what you are doing.The printed object is a dictionary so you have to access it like this and get the values for its keys:

```
NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [abogados objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *CodigoAbogado = [responseDictionary valueForKey:@"CodigoAbogado"];
NSString *Nombre [responseDictionary valueForKey:@"Nombre"];
```

This will store the values in strings.

Answer (score 0):

you json not valid json. so use convert to the taken from the value

```
 NSArray *accountArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];    


        for (NSDictionary *currDict in accountArray)
        {
           NSLog(@" value %@",[currDict objectForKey:@"Avis_Guardia"];
        }
```

Comment: See the code in first comment. The problem is resolved.